# Redirect loop with devise after_sign_in_path_for Devise 3.2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Even though I followed [the guide here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in).

I still get the redirect loop after the user has signed in.

This is what my routes looks like:

```
  devise_for :users, :path_names => { :sign_up => "register", 
                                      :sign_in => "login", 
                                      :sign_out => "logout",
                                                                            :settings => "settings" },
                    :controllers => { confirmations: "confirmations", 
                                      registrations: "users/registrations", 
                                      passwords: "users/passwords" }
```

And then I added this to my ApplicationController:

```
  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
    sign_in_url = new_user_session_url
    if request.referer == sign_in_url
      super
    else
      stored_location_for(resource) || request.referer || root_path
    end
  end
```

And then I added those respective methods to both `Users/RegistrationsController` and `Users/PasswordsController`.

Yet when I sign in, it still tells me there is a redirect loop and throws an error.

Thoughts?

Comment: Maybe the loop comes from another part of your code ? Did you had other things in your routes.rb ?

Comment: In after_sign_in_path_for is request.referer == sign_in_url?

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  params[:next] || super
end
```

Its always a bad idea to redirect user to referrers...

Answer (score 0):

I solved same issue with following helper method:

```
def back_or_default_path(default = root_path)
  referer = Addressable::URI.parse(request.env['HTTP_REFERER'])
  request_uri = Addressable::URI.parse(request.env['REQUEST_URI'])
  prohibited_paths = [request_uri.path]
  back = if params[:return_to].present?
    params[:return_to]
  elsif session[:return_to].present?
    session.delete(:return_to)
  elsif referer && !prohibited_paths.include?(referer.path) && root_url =~ /#{referer.host}/
    :back
  end

  back || default
end
```

Put it inside `ApplicationController`. Now you can use it like this:

```
def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  back_or_default_path(super)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the following code in my app working perfectly fine.

Put the following in your application controller or base controller

```
before_filter :store_location


  private

    def store_location

      # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.

      return unless request.get?

      if (request.path != "/users/sign_in" &&

          request.path != "/admins/sign_in" &&

          request.path != "/admin" &&

          request.path != "/users/sign_up" &&

          request.path != "/users/password/new" &&

          request.path != "/users/password/edit" &&

          request.path != "/users/confirmation" &&

          request.path != "/users/sign_out" &&

          !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls

        session[:previous_url] = request.fullpath

      end

    end


    def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)

      session[:previous_url] || root_path

    end


    def after_sign_out_path_for(resource)

      session[:previous_url] || root_path

    end
```

Another thing, i think `request.refferer` returns path and not url. Not sure.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this in `application_controller.rb`

```
before_filter :store_location
def store_location
  # store last url - this is needed for post-login redirect to whatever the user last visited.
  if (request.fullpath != "/users/sign_in" &&
      request.fullpath != "/users/sign_up" &&
      request.fullpath != "/users/password" &&
      request.fullpath != "/users/sign_out" &&
      !request.xhr?) # don't store ajax calls
    session["user_return_to"] = request.fullpath 
  end
end

def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  session[:user_return_to] || root_path
end
```